# Setting default value on a datbound checkbox list in ASP

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a form with a check box list in it. The check box list is databound to a table in the database. I need to set a default value for the check box when the pages loads and when I click a clear button to clear all the text boxes etc, that are on the form. Can someone tell me how to o that?

Answer (score 1):

//Check particular checkbox

```
    foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        if (item.Text.Trim() == "C#")//text or value (item.Value.Trim())
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }

    //check all checkbox
    foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        li.Selected = true;
    }
```

//uncheck

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(ListItem li in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        li.Selected = false;
    } 
}
```

Using jQuery clear all the inputs of form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Button1").click(function() {
        $('#form1').find(':input').each(function() {
            switch (this.type) {
            case 'password':
            case 'select-multiple':
            case 'select-one':
            case 'text':
            case 'textarea':
                $(this).val('');
                break;
            case 'checkbox':
            case 'radio':
                this.checked = false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```